# Python OpenCV convert image to byte string?

Tags: python, image, opencv, binary

I'm working with PyOpenCV. How to convert cv2 image (numpy) to binary string for writing to MySQL db without a temporary file and `imwrite`?

I googled it but found nothing...

I'm trying `imencode`, but it doesn't work.

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(url.path)
capture.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, float(url.query))
self.wfile.write(cv2.imencode('png', capture.read()))
```

Error:

```
  File "server.py", line 16, in do_GET
  self.wfile.write(cv2.imencode('png', capture.read()))
  TypeError: img is not a numerical tuple
```

Help somebody!

Answer (score 81):

If you have an image `img` (which is a numpy array) you can convert it into string using:

```
>>> img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tostring()
>>> type(img_str)
 'str'
```

Now you can easily store the image inside your database, and then recover it by using:

```
>>> nparr = np.fromstring(STRING_FROM_DATABASE, np.uint8)
>>> img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

where you need to replace `STRING_FROM_DATABASE` with the variable that contains the result of your query to the database containing the image.

Comment: have to use `cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)` for opencv3.0+

Comment: isn't tobytes() better than tostring(), just as numpy recommends using frombuffer() instead of fromstring()?

Comment: There is a weird blush color in my image, How to fix that?  https://imgur.com/OxdO7HB

Answer (score 12):

It works in 2020 with numpy==1.19.4 and opencv==4.4.0:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# get image from web camera
ret, frame = cam.read()

# convert to jpeg and save in variable
image_bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example:

```
def image_to_bts(frame):
    '''
    :param frame: WxHx3 ndarray
    '''
    _, bts = cv2.imencode('.webp', frame)
    bts = bts.tostring()
    return bts

def bts_to_img(bts):
    '''
    :param bts: results from image_to_bts
    '''
    buff = np.fromstring(bts, np.uint8)
    buff = buff.reshape(1, -1)
    img = cv2.imdecode(buff, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return img
```

Answer (score 5):

capture.read() returns a tuple, (err,img).

try splitting it up:

```
_,img = capture.read()
self.wfile.write(cv2.imencode('png', img))
```

Comment: it returns (True, array([[137], [ 80], [ 78], ..., [ 66], [ 96], [130]], dtype=uint8)), but not a byte string

Comment: How to convert that to byte string?

Comment: my solution is `self.wfile.write(numpy.array(cv2.imencode('.png', img)[1]).tostring())`

Answer (score 5):

```
im = cv2.imread('/tmp/sourcepic.jpeg')
res, im_png = cv2.imencode('.png', im)
with open('/tmp/pic.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(im_png.tobytes())
```

Answer (score 3):

My code to use opencv with python cgi :

```
    im_data = form['image'].file.read()
    im = cv2.imdecode( np.asarray(bytearray(im_data), dtype=np.uint8), 1 )
    ret, im_thresh = cv2.threshold( im, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "image/jpg")
    self.end_headers()      
    ret, buf = cv2.imencode( '.jpg', im_thresh )
    self.wfile.write( np.array(buf).tostring() )
```