# conversion from opencv image to jpeg image in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, video-capture

I'm grabbing frames from a video file as following:

```
def capture_frame(file):
        capture = cv.CaptureFromFile("video.mp4")
        cv.GetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
        cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 90000)
        frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
        return frame
```

The frame type is `cv2.cv.iplimage`. How can I convert this type of image to jpeg image without saving?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you can only convert to JPEG when you save! JPEG is compression procedure not opencv image type

Comment: as I already mentioned in your previous question, you should use `imencode`

Comment: I couldn't find a good example which shows how I can use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25592959/5008845

Comment: I get segmentation fault error after using the method above

Comment: post the code you tried so far... we can't guess which code you're using

Comment: frame = numpy.asarray(frame[:,:])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try just writing chunks?

```
with open('filename.jpeg', 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in image_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
```

Here's one worth looking at too that uses opencv natively http://answers.opencv.org/question/115/opencv-python-save-jpg-specifying-quality-gives-systemerror/. Although, not sure why you're trying to save `.mp4` to `.jpeg`...

Comment: Andrew, you misunderstood me. I don't want to save the file. I have to grab the frame, and send it as a jpg file to another function as a parameter.

Comment: I wish you actually answered the original question, because I'm stuck on this as well. I need to convert an `cv2.cv.iplimage` to a jpeg/array-of-bytes. So far I can't find anything on stack overflow that actually does this.

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you the bytes for a jpeg representation of the image.

```
def capture_frame(file):
        capture = cv.CaptureFromFile(file)
        cv.GetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
        cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 90000)
        frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
        return cv.EncodeImage('.jpg', frame).tostring()

capture_frame("video.mp4")
```

I've written out the results of `EncodeImage` to a file opened in binary (`open('somefile','wb')`) which resulted in a valid JPEG.

Comment: FYI cv2 now has `.imencode()` instead of `.EncodeImage()`