# How to convert a uint8 numpy array to an in-memory binary .jpg

Tags: numpy, computer-vision, opencv3.0

Basically, I need to do the reverse of this:

**cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(img_data, dtype=np.uint8), -1)**

I need to take a numpy image and convert to a in-memory jpg object.  Most of the routines that do his write it to disk.  I need it in an object.

Comment: cv2.imencode see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967320/python-opencv-convert-image-to-byte-string