# python , opencv, image array to binary

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I have a large image , using cv2 module in python and some coordinates i cropped the image:

```
  img = cv.imread(image_path)
  crop_img = img[y1:y2,x1:x2]
  cv.imwrite(cropPath, crop_img)
```

now the crop_img is a numpy.ndarray type. then I save this image to disk and read its contents in a binary format using an open() function

```
  with open(cropPath, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
```

and I get the binary representation.
Is there any way to do the above operations without saving the image to disk. Not saving to disk will save a lot of time, I am not able to find any method to do this. if anyone could point in the right direction, that would be helpful.

Comment: You can use a [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) to save the data to a fake file in RAM.

Comment: Why do you need to write to a file?

Comment: When you say `binary`,  do you mean binary string or numbers or something else?

Comment: By binary i mean binarystring, the output from using 'rb' parameter for open() function

Comment: posted the answer found on another thread, i got tangled in the encoding, thank you guys for help

Answer (score 5):

**found the answer on this thread:**
[Python OpenCV convert image to byte string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967320/python-opencv-convert-image-to-byte-string)

converting a image represented through a numpy array into string can be done by using imencode and tostring functions in cv2

```
>>> img_str = cv.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tostring()
>>> type(img_str)
 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `cv2.imwrite()`， then you will get an image in image format,such as `png, jpg, bmp` and so on. Now if you `open(xxx,"rb")`  as a normal binary file, it will go wrong, because it is `AN IMAGE in IMAGE FILE FORMAT`.

The simplest way is use `np.save()` to save the `np.ndarray` to the disk (`serialize`) in .npy format. The use `np.load()` to load from disk (`deserialize`).

An alternative is `pickle.dump()/pickle.load()`.

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.10.04 21:39:35 CST

import pickle 
imgname = "Pictures/cat.jpg"

## use cv2.imread()/cv2.imwrite() 
img = cv2.imread(imgname)

## use np.save() / np.load()
np.save(open("another_cat1.npy","wb+"), img)
cat1 = np.load(open("another_cat1.npy","rb"))

## use pickle.dump() / pickle.load()
pickle.dump(img, open("another_cat2.npy","wb+"))
cat2 = pickle.load(open("another_cat2.npy", "rb"))

cv2.imshow("img", img);
cv2.imshow("cat1", cat1);
cv2.imshow("cat2", cat2);
cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result:

[image]