# opencv image encodeing returns array, instead of buffer

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am having a problem with converting encoded image to string. I encode as below:

```
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
_, buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', image)
```

When I try to call, `buffer.toString()`, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toString'
```

There are many questions on stackoverflow related to the same functionality that I am doing(Encoding with opencv). The following are few, which has contradicting answers.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25592959/7621143

In this answer, it is implied that `imencode` returns a tuple, with 2 elements:

```
>>> img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tostring()
>>> type(img_str)
 'str'
```

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17970817/7621143

Another answer to the same question, implies that the result is one value.

Anyway, in my case, the return value is a tuple with 2 elements, where the 2nd one is an `ndarray`, which doesn't have `toString()` method.

FWIW,

```
$ pip show opencv-python
Name: opencv-python
Version: 3.4.3.18
$ pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.15.4
```

OpenCV documentation for [imencode](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#cv2.imencode) says, the return value is a tuple with 2 elements & the 2nd one is buffer.

```
Python: cv2.imencode(ext, img[, params]) → retval, buf
```

Any suggestions are appreciative, to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error clearly says:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toString'

which means that you have mis-spelled the method. Replace `toString` with `tostring` to get the desired results.