# Upload image from opencv to s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-s3, raspberry-pi

I am trying to upload image to s3 after detecting a face using opencv. The jpg file gets uploaded to s3 but I am not able to open the image.

I am able to upload correctly by first saving the image to local disk and then uploading it to s3 but I want to directly do it after detecting the face. Any idea how it can be done?

```
# import the necessary packages

# capture frames from the camera

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # cv2.imwrite('newobama.png', image)

    if len(faces):
        imageName = str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M")) + '.jpg'
        #This is not working
        s3.put_object(Bucket="surveillance-cam", Key = imageName, Body = bytes(image), ContentType= 'image/jpeg')   

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Comment: I normally find that it is easiest to save a picture to the local disk, then upload that file to Amazon S3. This way, you can test the contents of the picture before sending it to S3 (good for debugging!). It also avoids the whole Body/Bytes requirement.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein True, but I am using rasberrypi and have very limited space. But I think I will write in above script to delete the images as soon as they are done uploading.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
    s3.put_object(Bucket="surveillance-cam", Key = imageName, Body = bytes(image), ContentType= 'image/jpeg')
```

by

```
image_string = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tostring()
s3.put_object(Bucket="surveillance-cam", Key = imageName, Body=image_string)
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
import boto3
import cv2


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket-name')
src_dir = 'target_directory_on_aws/'


image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image_string = cv2.imencode('.png', image)[1].tostring()

client.put_object(
    Bucket='my-bucket-name',
    Key=target_aws_path,  # format: '/my_image.png'
    Body=image_string
)
```

Comment: This works but not effective for real time. Fps is highly dropped down. I think the better way would be to just save file - upload - delete

Answer (score 0):

I belive the `image` object is not a JPEG-encoded binary representation. It's a NumPy object for Mathematic purposes

You should check for [Python OpenCV convert image to byte string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967320/python-opencv-convert-image-to-byte-string) and

```
imencode
```

[Encodes an image](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imencode) into a memory buffer. To generate an object that S3 can take

Answer (score 0):

pip install Pillow

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

img = Image.fromarray(image)
out_img = BytesIO()
img.save(out_img, format='png')
out_img.seek(0)
s3.put_object(Bucket="Bucket Name", Key = imageName, Body = local_image, ContentType= 'image/png')
```

This code worked for me, but it is giving a little blue shade to the uploaded image. So I decided to go with first saving the image to local disk and then uploading to S3

```
cv2.imwrite(imageName, image)
local_image = open('./'+imageName, 'rb')
s3.put_object(Bucket="Bucket Name", Key = imageName, Body = local_image, ContentType= 'image/png')
```

Comment: blue shade is due to color scheme being changed from RGB to BGR

Answer (score 0):

```
is_success, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
io_buf = BytesIO(buffer)
s3.upload_fileobj(io_buf, "bucket-name", "file_name")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.