# How to send and recieve a cv2 image in the form of numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sockets, websocket

I'm an intermediate in python and new to libraries like numpy and opencv. I'm trying to make a video calling app using sockets.This code is just a try. I've tried in the following way but as it receives the array it's size becomes 0 and shape becomes null. Please help me do this. I'm sorry for anymistakes I've done

any help will be appreciated

Thank you. Have a nice day enter

Server:-

```
import socket
import threading
from _thread import *
import cv2
import numpy as np

srvr = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 9999
client = []
try: 
    srvr.bind((server_ip, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)



def connected_client(conn, addr):
    global client
    print("[SERVER]: CONNECTED WITH ", addr)
    check_msg = "Welcome Client"
    conn.send(str.encode(check_msg))
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(5000)
            if not data:
                print("[SERVER]: DISCONNECTED..")
                break
            for i in client:
                i.sendall(data)
        except:
            break
        
    conn.close()


srvr.listen(5)
while True:
    print("[SERVER]: STARTED...\n [SERVER]: ACCEPTING CONNECTIONS....")
    conn, addr = srvr.accept()
    start_new_thread(connected_client, (conn, addr))
    client.append(conn)
```

Client:-

```
import socket, cv2
import threading
from _thread import *
import numpy as np
import time
import base64

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

clt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 9999
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

clt.connect(ADDR)
print(clt.recv(2048).decode())
#recieving data from server
def recieve():
    global clt
    while True:
            recv_frame = clt.recv(5000)
            nparr = np.frombuffer(recv_frame, np.uint8)
            img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == ord('a'):
                break
            print(img)
            # cv2.imshow("aman", recv_frame)
            
            # break
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967320/python-opencv-convert-image-to-byte-string

# new thread while to continuously recieve data
start_new_thread(recieve, ())

# loop for continuously sending data
while True:
    check, frame = video.read()
    str_frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()
    clt.sendall(str_frame)


video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can client receive and decode string data?

Comment: yes the client can recieve the string data and decode it in a form such that it can be used to form an image. Thank you forcontribution, very glad to have you